# How to read file remotely?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++

I have such a method for reading file by path

```
void test_read_file(std::string const & fileName)
{
    std::ifstream file(fileName);
    if (!file.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "LoadFromFile FAILED to load: " << fileName << std::endl;   <--- this line
    }

    ...
}
```

And this method works well if I pass as a path `C:\\...`, but if I pass something like this `\\\\my_remote_drive\\my_user\\....` it does not work and I came to line that I marked above.

It looks like a lack of permission or something like this...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: AFAIK `fstream` work with local files. So maybe try mounting the remote disk locally using sshfs or NFS (not sure if that's available on windows). Or maybe using something else on top of some network protocol like FTP.

Comment: Maybe the simplest way to go is download the file to a temp folder then open it.

Comment: `std::(i|o)fstream()` works with any file represented by a valid path string. It delegates to the underlying OS to actually open the file. Windows APIs can open a UNC path, provided a valid network connection to the UNC share. I have to assume the problem is related to permissions, as the OP surmised. Use [`CreateFile()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) directly to verify that. If `CreateFile()` fails, use [`GetLastError()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) to find out why

Comment: @RemyLebeau I work with CLI implementation and I see that if I try to read this file from c# code it is ok, but if I try to do the same on c++ side, it fails... So, I assume that it should not be permission issue

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko can't answer that without seeing a [mcve]

Comment: you need first call `NetUseAdd` for `\\\\my_remote_drive\\IPC$` and set user name/pass

Comment: @RemyLebeau what do you mean minimal reproducible example? there is a method in question, just pass there a pass to your remote driver and you will see a result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a connection to a network resource first, with [`WNetAddConnection2A`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetaddconnection2a)(Similar APIs are [`NetUseAdd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmuse/nf-lmuse-netuseadd), [`NPAddConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/npapi/nf-npapi-npaddconnection), etc.) and this function could also redirect a local device to the network resource.

`lpRemoteName`:

An example for a share might be the following: `\192.168.1.1\share`

```
NETRESOURCE nr = {0};
nr.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_ANY;
nr.lpLocalName = NULL; //does not assign a drive.
nr.lpRemoteName = "\\192.168.1.1\\share";

DWORD ret = WNetAddConnection2 (&nr, NULL, NULL, CONNECT_TEMPORARY);
```

To assigning a Drive to a Share:
You could refer to [Assigning a Drive to a Share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wnet/assigning-a-drive-to-a-share)